# II order nonlinear ODE, regularity of the solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the following ODE

$$
\frac{d^2}{ dt^2 }x(t) = F(x(t)),\:  x(0) = x_0, \quad (t,x) \in [0,T]\times, \mathbf{R}^d 
$$
where $F$ is a nonlinear term.

The question is: what kind of conditions on $F$ yield the following regularity for $x(t)$
$$
|x(t) - x(0)|\leq C|t|^{\alpha}, \quad 0 < \alpha \leq 1
$$

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Continuity of $F$ around $x_0$ is enough. The standard theory of existence implies that for any $y_0\in\mathbb{R}^d$ there is a solution $x\colon[-T,T]\to\mathbb{R}^d$ of class $C^2$ such that $x(0)=x_0$ and $x'(0)=y_0$, where $T>0$ dependes on $F$, $x_0$ and $y_0$. If in addition $F$ is Lipschitz, then the solution is unique. In any case, since $x(t)$ is $C^2$, we have
$$
x(t)=x_0+t\,y_0+O(t^2)
$$
and
$$
|x(y)-x_0|\le C\,t
$$
for some constant $C$ and $|t|\le T$.

Comment: Dear Julián, thank you for the answer!
In this case the constant C depends from the initial value. I was after a global estimate, with $C$ independent from the initial value $(x_0,y_0)$. Thank you anyway!

Comment: In any case the constant will depend on $x'(0)$.